# save checked items in table view for later reuse in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa

Got a conceptual question: If I got a tableview with about 100 items and the user can check as many as he wants from that list, how and where do I save the checked status of each individual item for later reuse?

Answer (score 1):

In your own internal structures.  UITableView isn't a database.  It merely is an interface to your data.  Any selection, deletion, addition, etc. will have to be handled by your code and stored.  Typically you have some sort of a database or structure associated with the UITableView elements.  When you get a check action, you can update a variable in that structure.

For an example of an SQL database backed UITableView app, see [here](http://icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/).

Answer (score 0):

For storing the checked elements of tableview, you have to maintain your code in didselectRow mthos of tableview. So, whenever you check the tableview row you can save it in an array. And save that array in the "NSUSerDefaul". So, that whenever you close the application, you can get back your selected tableview row array from "NSUserDefault". Or you can use sqlite database but it is better to use NSUserDefault as there is simple thing to do.

Please give your response if you find any problem.

You can use NSUSerDefault in your application from the following link: click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074483/save-string-to-the-nsuserdefaults)