# Font and Font Size Changing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a Mac app with a plain-text text view. I have been able to get it to save, etc, but when I change the font or font size in my app using the font panel, it is not saved when the app re-opens.

How can I create a way that my app will save the font and font size changes? Thanks!

Comment: How are you saving the text now?

Comment: I am saving it as a .txt file in the Mobile Documents folder.

Answer (score 1):

Save Font and Font Size in [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and load from NSUserDefault at the time of application launching.

```
NSString *valueToSave = @"someValue";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"preferenceName"];
to get it back later

NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    stringForKey:@"preferenceName"];
```

Take a look at [Save string to the NSUserDefaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074483/save-string-to-the-nsuserdefaults) post.

Comment: Do you have some code for that? Sorry, I am new to this programming thing.

Comment: Take a look at [Save string to the NSUserDefaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074483/save-string-to-the-nsuserdefaults) post.