# How to save a button's hidden state as a NSUserDefault?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, nsuserdefaults, hidden

Bellow I have some code that simply hides a button through a delegation system in Xcode. I believe that this all works however when I transfer views back to the 'leveSelector' view the delegate is not valid so the button does not show as un-hidden. Because of this I would like to apply some `NSUserDefaults` to save the button state so that when I go back to the'levelComplete' view later in the game I would like the button to be un-hidden.

Here I have the code for the `delegate` system i am using:

**Here I have the levelComplete code...
.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "levelComplete.h"
#import "LevelSelector.h"

@interface levelComplete : UIViewController{
  }
 @property (nonatomic, strong) id<CustomDelegate> delegatePpty;

 @end
```

**.m**

```
@implementation levelComplete
@synthesize delegatePpty;

-(void)someAction
 {
[self.delegatePpty hideUnhidebutton:YES];//Call the delegate method to execute
 }


 - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
     [self someAction]; // Here I call my action
   }
@end
```

Here I have the leveSelector code...

**.h**

```
  @protocol CustomDelegate <NSObject>
  -(void)hideUnhidebutton:(BOOL)value;
  @end

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "levelComplete.h"
#import "LevelSelector.h"

@interface LevelSelector : UIViewController <CustomDelegate>{        

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *level1;

@end
```

**.m**

```
@implementation LevelSelector
@synthesize level1;

-(void)hideUnhidebutton:(BOOL)value
 {
  [self.level1 setHidden:value];

  }
```

So to clarify I would like to save the button when it has been hidden as a `NSUserDefault`.
In this case the button I desire to hide is called `level1`.

Edit: thanks to everybody who posted apply your code worked great

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save string to the NSUserDefaults?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074483/save-string-to-the-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sapi's answer already covers your comment **How would I go about loading the NSUserDefaults**

```
BOOL yourBoolValue = YES;

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:yourBoolValue] forKey:@"YourVariableKey"];
```

The last line has already the result you want. The [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] is a singleton and also persistent, so you can create it in every context, having the same instance.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL restoredBoolValue = [[defaults objectForKey:@"YourVariableKey"] boolValue];
[self.level1 setHidden:restoredBoolValue];
```

Ant that's it.
You can basically save everything in the NSUserDefaults. Just check out [Apple's reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can save a value to `NSUserDefaults` in a straightforward manner:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:value]
             forKey:@"SomeSensibleKey"];
```

You can check the saved state with:

```
[[defaults objectForKey:@"SomeSensibleKey"] boolValue]
```

Comment: The first line of the code above loads the standard defaults dictionary for your app.  Unless you have special needs (which, from the question, I don't believe you do) that should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

To save a boolean value to user defaults you have to call setBool method:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"ButtonHiddenKey"];
```

To load a boolean value from user defaults (in init method):

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
button.hidden = [defaults boolForKey:@"ButtonHiddenKey"];
```

There are also messages to store other types of variables such as setInteger, setFloat and so on