# Keep text in text field persistent, even when switching view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to be able keep the text in a textfield persistent as I switch between view controllers.
 I'm making a login screen and the login. However, if I go back to the login view controller after being in another view controller, the login information disappears (I'm pretty sure it's because it's a new instance of the view controller).
What I want to happen is that if a user enters in their login information and then goes back to the login view controller, they don't have to retype their info in.

Edit: Here is code for my programmatic segue to switch view controllers:

```
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondViewController"];
secondViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
```

Comment: What type of segue are you using?

Comment: A programmatic segue. I put the code in the question

Comment: Can you show me your viewDidLoad and/or viewDidAppear?

Comment: My viewDidLoad only has [super viewDidLoad]; However, my viewDidUnLoad has [textField resignFirstResponder]; in it. I tried commenting that out, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Check out my answer below and tell me if it helps.

Comment: Which controller is the login controller? The first one, or the one you're calling SecondViewController in your question?

Comment: The login controller is the first one

Comment: If login is the first controller, it shouldn't be deallocated when you dismiss SecondViewController. How are you going from Second back to login?

Comment: Another button in the second view controller. It is linked through the storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Embed your first controller in a navigation bar. Next take out that code and use:

```
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to persist across launches of the program, then you should store the login information  whenever they change it, and then read it back in whenever your login view controller loads and set the text field values from that.

You can store the information in a couple of different ways:

**iOS Keychain**
See this SO question for an example of how to store information securely in the keychain:
[iOS: How to store username/password within an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6972092/937822)

**NSUserDefaults**
If you are only storing the username (and not the password) then you could use NSUserDefaults.
See this question for a good example:
[Save string to the NSUserDefaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3074483/937822)

Answer (score 0):

If the login controller is the first controller, the window's root view controller, it won't be deallocated unless you change which controller is the root. This doesn't happen when you're presenting and dismissing modal view controllers. I'm guessing that you're going from SecondViewController "back" to login controller by doing another modal presentation. Is that what you're doing? If so, that's wrong, that does create a new instance of login controller as you suspected. Instead, you should dismiss SecondViewController when you want to go back to the login controller. You need to do this in code rather than using a segue in the storyboard.