# Pause NSTimer when leaving that view and continue counting when come back?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, nstimer

I'm new in xcode and objective-c and trying to developing an app. I would like to set up a timer in some of pages for calculating how much time user spend in that page. In the app, I have 5 theme pages, each pages contains a table view to another 3 sub-pages. I would like to add a counter to these 3 pages (5*3) but not including theme pages themselves. The page shift is controlled by navigation bar. I have put some codes as follows in .m file of viewcontroller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad  
{
[super viewDidLoad];
//timer
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self 
                                       selector:@selector(handleTimer) 
                                       userInfo:nil 
                                        repeats:YES];
}

-(void)handleTimer
{
MainInt += 1;
self.TimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",MainInt];
}
```

and some code in .h file (Brett is one of the 3 sub-pages.)

```
@interface Brett : UIviewController
{
NSTimer *timer;
int MainInt;
}

@ property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILable *TimLable;
```

Every time when I leave the page and go back again the counter is always count from 0. Anyone can help to solve this problem??

Comment: Create that timer in appDelegate

Comment: You can also use user defaults to store the value. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074483/save-string-to-the-nsuserdefaults

Answer (score 3):

Every time it Count start form 0, I guess because of you are creating **Brett** object every time when you push it to navigation.

Create Global Timer in appDelegate class and use it,
in `viewWillAppear` **start** timer and in `viewWillDisappear` **pause** that timer.

Comment: I think I did not explain properly, in my app, I have 5 theme pages, each pages contains a table view to another 3 sub-pages. I would like to add a counter to these 3 pages (5*3) but not including theme pages themselves. Brett is one of the 3 sub-pages.

Comment: could you kindly show me how to do that?? i would be very appreciative

Comment: @Richard: Use Global Timer in appDelegate.

Comment: I have explain you in simple words.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to the other answer, you can just make the `MainInt` a static variable

```
static int MainInt;
```

Comment: hi I got error of type name does not allow storage class to be specified?

Comment: You cannot declare a static variable as an ivar. Declare it in the .m file right after the #import stuff.

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from your question is to simply keep track of the amount of time a user spend in sub pages. If my understanding is correct, then you may try following.

Create and start timer as like now you are doing.
On `viewWillDisAppear` method of your controller, just update the global variable or `NSUserDefaults` value like this:

```
//Get the previous time available in userdefaults
int counter = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"ScreenACounter"];
//Update the key with existing counter value + current timer value.
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:counter + currentTimer.Value  forKey:@"HighScore"];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tha's what i understood, and was going to suggest :)