# Error while converting nsdata to nsstring

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I'm trying to convert `NSData` to `NSString` 
Here's my code

```
NSData *Data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"phoneNumber"];
NSString *getPhone = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[Data bytes]];
NSLog(@"%@",getPhone);
```

And the error I'm getting is

```
 -[__NSCFData rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: How did you saved it?

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myPhoneString forKey:@"phoneNumber"];

Comment: Look there:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074483/save-string-to-the-nsuserdefaults

Comment: Why are you not using `initWithData`??

Comment: BTW, that's not the code that's giving you the error.  It's occurring somewhere else.  (Learn how to read an exception stack trace.)

Comment: I think NSData which you save to NSUserDefaults is wrong. Let's check it again

Comment: @HotLicks No, it's the code that gives an error. I get a green line on [Data bytes] line when it gives the error.

Comment: Clean your project and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change:

```
NSString getPhone = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"phoneNumber"];  
NSLog(@"%@",getPhone);
```

hm, strange issue. you can print out getPhone directly after set user defaults to understand if some other part of code does not modify it. [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myPhoneString forKey:@"phoneNumber"];

So try this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", myPhoneString); // check current value
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myPhoneString forKey:@"phoneNumber"];
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"phoneNumber"]) // check value after set it.
```

values should be the same, but also you will need to print this value in another place to test if some other code have not modified it. (I mean in place where you print it `NSLog(@"%@",getPhone);`)

Alos be sure that you set NSString to the NSUserDefault instead of data because as I see in your example you set NSString and output NSString as well so you don't need NSData in this your case.

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't give my phoneNumber, It gives me something like <87172 81727 33>

Comment: I think it should be ```stringForKey``` instead of ```objectForKey```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString * getPhone = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    stringForKey:@"phoneNumber"];
```