# How to save cookies in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies

How to save cookies, and then stick them in a query? I understand that this is a stupid question, but I can not find a solution not.

Comment: use [`NSUserDefaults`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3074489/1066828)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write sometime after the first request to the server (authorization - when cookies do not need to pass)

```
NSData *cookieData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:cookieData forKey:@"ApplicationCookie"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Then, when the application starts every time pull cookies from NSUserDefaults, if they are there then:

```
NSData *cookieData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ApplicationCookie"];
if ([cookieData length] > 0) {
    NSArray *cookies = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:cookieData];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {
        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
     }
}
```

Comment: This is an incredibly! thank you!