# Taking user input from UITextField and saving as string in ViewController without using segues

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have looked all over the internet for an answer to this question and I have tried multiple different suggested ways but it still won't work.

I have a single `UIViewController` with a `UITextField` and two `UIButtons`. One to save the input as a string and another to segue into another view. In other view I just have a `UILabel`. All I want to do is take the text the user input, save it as a string in the second `UIViewController` and then be able to display it. The trick is that I don't want to have to use segues.

This is my code:

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {


SecondViewController *detailViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

detailViewController.str = _TextField.text;

[self.TextField resignFirstResponder];
}
@end
```

SecondViewController.h

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *str;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Label;

@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

[_Label setText:_str];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

If someone could tell me what is wrong with the code that would be really helpful.
When I run the app and type in text, then go to SecondView the label will show up empty.

Comment: Try, `self.Label.text = self.str;`

Comment: The SecondViewController still came up with a blank label

Comment: The problem might with your buttons. You'r about to assign in one action and just segue with another, right ? ..

Comment: Yeah, I have one button linked to IBAction, that is the save button, and then I linked the other button, next, to segue to the SecondViewController

Comment: that's the reason, here actually when you'r about to segue the viewController gets re-initialised, so the str could be empty

Comment: So how could I fix that?

Comment: override this method `-prepareForSegue:sender:`

Comment: Sorry, I am relatively new to xcode, could you give me a piece of sample code? And where I should add that method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your segue,

No need to assign in one of the action, which is not responsible for the segue.

Just override this method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        SecondViewController *detailViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController.str = _TextField.text;
    }
}
```

> The trick is that I don't want to have to use segues.

Then go with the [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) -- [Save string to the NSUserDefaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074483/save-string-to-the-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: If I wanted to save TextField.text to a ViewController other then the one that I am setting up the segue to, would this still work? In the original question I had said that I wanted to try and avoid having to send it through a segue

Comment: then just go with the `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: Any chance you could show me what that would look like?

Comment: Thank you so much! I just got it to work! I have been working on this for almost a week now!

Answer (score 0):

In this function you also do pushView Controller

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

     SecondViewController *detailViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController.str = _TextField.text;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:NO];
    [self.TextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

try this may be helpfull..

Comment: I added the pushViewController to my code and it didn't make any difference. When I push the save button the keyboard is dismissed, and then when I press the button to go to the next view it still showed up empty.

Comment: So I added this in ViewController:   NSLog(@"%@", detailViewController.str);
And this in SecondViewController:    NSLog(@"%@", self.str);
In ViewController it came up as my string but in SecondViewController it came up null

Comment: try to clean project and build again .. Because code is correct.

Comment: I did a clean build and it didn't work. Does it matter if my views are embedded in a Navigation controller? And does it matter how I set up the segue?

Comment: does matter of segue only

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

 SecondViewController *detailViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
detailViewController.str = _TextField.text;

[self.TextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

I deleted this code
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:NO];
as this code prompts to push the view controller.

Hope this helps :)