# Change NSString value for ever : NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsuserdefaults

I have two views :

View1 (Shop) : URL stocked in `NSString` for displaying image.

View2 (ModifyShop) : Text field with URL from view1.

I can pass data from view1 to view2 : The URL stocked in `NSString` appears in Text field and pass data from view2 to view1. (URL for example)

Now I would like to modify this URL with Text field from view2 and that modify the `NSString` in view1 for ever. How can I make that ? Using `NSUserDefaults` ?

Here is my code :

Shop:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.modifyButton setHidden:YES];

}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"admin"]) {
        NSLog(@"pas admin");
    } else {
        [self.modifyButton setHidden:NO];
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
        self.imageButtonURL = @"http://bundoransurfshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/72-torq-pink.jpg";
        imageButtonData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:self.imageButtonURL]];
        if ( imageButtonData == nil )
            return;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.imageButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageButtonData];
        });
    });
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"modifyShop"]) {
        ShopModify *viewcontroller = (ShopModify *)segue.destinationViewController;
    viewcontroller.imageButtonURL = self.imageButtonURL;      }
}

-(IBAction)prepareForUnwindShopModify:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    NSLog(@"%@", self.imageButtonURL);
}
```

Shopmodify:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.photoURL.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.imageButtonURL];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        Shop *viewcontroller = (Shop *)segue.destinationViewController;
        viewcontroller.imageButtonURL = self.photoURL.text;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If with foverer you mean even after you close and open again your app, replacing the default http://bundoransurfshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/72-torq-pink.jpg, yes, for example you could use NSUserDefaults (or any other persistent way to store your data/configuration).

**Save on edit in view2:**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave 
                                          forKey:@"imageUrl"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; //Important
```

**Load/Reload in view1:**

```
NSString *savedUrl = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"imageUrl"];
if(!savedValue){
   savedUrl = @"http://bundoransurfshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/72-torq-pink.jpg";
}
```

Official documentation for [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults).

Answer (score 2):

You can store a URL string in NSUserDefaults by following this post:

[Save string to the NSUserDefaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074483/save-string-to-the-nsuserdefaults)

Simply have your view1 always get it from NSUserDefaults in viewWillAppear and have view2 change the NSUserDefaults key for the URL string and that should do it