# Swift iOS - Set highscore in gameScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm making some great progress with my first iOS game app, currently I'm working on the high score element and if anyone would be so kind as to help guide me how to use the correct code.

I've followed a few tutorials with mixed results, so far I'm increasing the score count by 1 for each screen press (will be changed but using for the purpose for this post), this works fine however I need some help saving both the high score using `NSUserDefaults` and also displaying the high score.

Below is the extract of my code, currently the score works fine however the high score remains at 0 and doesn't increase.  Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code.....

Thank you.

EDITED WITH REWORKED CODE

```
// in gameScene:

var scoreLabelNode = SKLabelNode()
var score = NSInteger()
var highScoreLabelNode = SKLabelNode()
var highScore = NSInteger()

// in did move to view

    score = 0
    scoreLabelNode.fontName = "Helvetica-Bold"
    scoreLabelNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2.8, y: self.frame.size.height / 1.2 )
    scoreLabelNode.fontSize = 20
    scoreLabelNode.alpha = 0.2
    scoreLabelNode.zPosition = -30
    scoreLabelNode.text = "Score \(score)"
    self.addChild(scoreLabelNode)

// start of high score

    var highScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if (highScoreDefault.valueForKey("highScore") != nil){
        highScore = highScoreDefault.valueForKey("highscore") as! NSInteger!
        highScoreLabelNode.text = NSString(format: "highscore : %i", highScore) as String
    }

//        highScore = 0
//        if (score > highScore) {
//            highScore = score
//            highScoreLabelNode.text = NSString(format: "highscore : %i", highScore) as String
//        }


    highScoreLabelNode.fontName = "Helvetica-Bold"
    highScoreLabelNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2.6, y: self.frame.size.height / 1.3 )

    highScoreLabelNode.fontSize = 20
    highScoreLabelNode.alpha = 0.2
    highScoreLabelNode.zPosition = -30
    highScoreLabelNode.text = "High Score \(score)"
    self.addChild(highScoreLabelNode)

// in touches began 

            let incrementScore = SKAction.runBlock ({
                ++self.score
                self.scoreLabelNode.text = "Score \(self.score)"
            })

            self.runAction(incrementScore)

// in update before each frame

//    highScore = 0
if (score > highScore) {
    highScore = score
    highScoreLabelNode.text = NSString(format: "highscore : %i", highScore) as String
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it seems you dont ever call

```
 if (score > highScore) {
    highScore = score
    highScoreLabelNode.text = NSString(format: "highscore : %i", highScore) as String
}
```

again anywhere, which is where your highscore is set? Is it called somewhere that is not indicated in the code you have provided?

Comment: thanks for the reply, there isn't any more code and your right I don't call the code at all, how and where would you suggest I could do this?

Comment: you preferably should put that part into a method. call it func updateHighScore for example. And call that method whenever you are ready to check if your current score is higher than the highscore. For example: when the game ends (when player dies or whatever)

Comment: please mark my reply as the answer if that answered your question. If you have any further questions, i can try to help.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much.  I have the slight issue of the highscore not saving, would you know what i need to change in my code to fix?

Comment: you should look into saving into NSUserDefaults. Look into this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074483/save-string-to-the-nsuserdefaults

Comment: mark my reply as answer please. Thants how stackoverflow works ;)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you are not saving the highscore to User Defaults with NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.setObject(), also, I'm not sure why you are setting highScore to 0

Comment: Thank you for spotting this, would you know what i could change to my code to make the highscore save?