# Pass data between two classes in two files

Tags: ios, swift, segue, xib

I have two swift files. one file has a variable with some data. I need to use data in that variable from another class.

Class A

```
class HVListConnectionsRequest: HVRequest {

    var connections = [HVConnection]()
    //Some code
}
```

Class B

```
class HVListConnectionsController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Please tell me how can I print data in `connections` variable in Class B.

I am not using storyboard and I am using XIB files and MVC
design pattern, so please tell me how can do it without using segues.

Comment: global variable? or maybe a struct with all the vars you need on both of them

Comment: @LeoDabus i can not use this as static variable because i am appending data to connections on the instance

Comment: You can always add a willSet and do whatever you need before changing its value http://stackoverflow.com/a/34486265/2303865

Comment: In additions to Leo:s tips above, possibly using a custom protocol for delegate callbacks between from HV-class to some delegate object in your view controller (possibly do callbacks using property observers as mentioned by Leo, e.g. willSet). See e.g. https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/04/08/how-delegation-works-a-swift-developer-guide/

Comment: you should create a new var in class B  make an instance of your class B  in Class A , then set it  ( before push or present)

Answer (score 1):

> I have two swift files. one file has a variable with some data. I need to use data in that variable from another class.

What you're really trying to do is to use data in another *object*. `connections` is a property of `HVListConnectionsRequest`, so each instance of `HVListConnectionsRequest` has its own value for `connections`.

Moving data between objects is a fundamental task in object oriented programming, and doing it requires that one object have a reference to another object. In this case, you need your `HVListConnectionsController` object to somehow get a reference to the instance of `HVListConnectionsRequest` that you care about. There are many ways to make that happen, for example:

- A `HVListConnectionsController` can create a new `HVListConnectionsRequest`.
- Some other object can give a `HVListConnectionsRequest` object to an `HVListConnectionsController`.
- A `HVListConnectionsController` can fetch a `HVListConnectionsRequest` from some well-known location or object.

Once your `HVListConnectionsController` has a reference to a `HVListConnectionsRequest`, then getting it's `connections` property is obviously simple. For example, if `someRequest` points to the connections request:

```
let myConnections = someConnectionsRequest.connections
```

So, you need to think about the relationship between `HVListConnectionsRequest` and `HVListConnectionsController`... how are `HVListConnectionsRequest` objects created? You say that you're using MVC; are `HVListConnectionsRequest`s part of your app's data model, and if so, can the `HVListConnectionsController` get the connections request from the model? Or are they perhaps created by the same view controller that creates the `HVListConnectionsViewController`, and if so, can that view controller pass the request along when it creates a `HVListConnectionsViewController'?

In short, I can't tell you how one object in your app should talk to another without knowing more about how those objects are created in your app. The good news is that I don't need to tell you, either... once you're looking at the relationships between objects, you'll be on track to solve this problem yourself.

One thing I can tell you, though, is that you'll do well to avoid "easy" solutions like creating a singleton or storing the data in the user defaults system. You're dealing with a pretty typical OO design issue, and punting to user defaults or making everything in your app accessible to everything else simply avoid the design problem; the result will be a poorly designed app that becomes increasingly difficult to work on.

Answer (score -1):

You can use NSUserDefaults to store connection data. and On another Class B you can get Connection data from NSUserDefaults.

Too see how you can save and get value in NSUserDefaults please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3074489/4030948).