# Storing a variable in swift after passing it

Tags: swift, tableview

I have a variable that is passed between two tableview controllers.The cells in the first tableview have a detail label that is updated by this variable that is passed from the second one. once the string is passed i want it to save and bump out the old string.I would like the variable to stay saved until the app is uninstalled.  any idea on how i would do this ? passing the data with protocol. I appreciate any help!

Comment: You can use `UserDefulats` for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save string to the NSUserDefaults?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074483/save-string-to-the-nsuserdefaults)