# How to play video from where i stopped previously. from remote server url

Tags: ios, xcode, avplayerviewcontroller, avasset, mpmediaplayercontroller

I am playing video from remote url. Suppose stopped playing the video and later again I am trying to play the same video. Now, I have to play from where i stopped previously. Like VLC Player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you leave the ViewController in which you are playing the video, for example in the `viewWillDisappear`, you can save in the `NSUserDefault` the time value where you stopped playing the video (if there is still something to watch).

Indeed, in the `viewWillAppear` then, you can check this value from the `NSUserDefault` every time before playing the video.
So that, if you have a value for the key : `"timeLeftPlaying"` for example, you can load the video directly at this value.

**Getter** and **Setter** in order to *store* or *retrieve* value from `NSUserDefault` :

```
+(NSString *)getTimeLeftPlaying
{
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"timeLeftPlaying"];
}

+(void) setTimeLeftPlaying:(NSString *)timeLeft
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:timeLeft forKey:@"timeLeftPlaying"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}
```

**NB:** I recommend you to create a custom class in order to regroup all the methods relative to `NSUserDefault`, so that you can access it easily from anywhere.

If you never play around `NSUserDefault` I'd recommend checking this helpful links :

[Apple Official Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults)

[StackOverflow Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074483/save-string-to-the-nsuserdefaults)

Hope it will help you and give you enough informations to start your feature.