# How can I store a property holding a custom user type to regulate which view controllers a user sees?

Tags: ios, swift, access-control

Context: I have two user types. Depending on which user type you are, the same view controller will appear with different features, controls etc.

How can I store this property about the current user that is always available whenever I am instantiating a view controller to define what they can and can't see/do as the VC loads?

Comment: set a global variable.

Comment: store the user type in user defaults. Reset it on login and logout. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203241/how-can-i-use-userdefaults-in-swift https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074483/save-string-to-the-nsuserdefaults

Answer (score 0):

You can get random identifier using uuid:

```
guard let userIdentifier = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString else { return }
```

You can store it with UserDefaults:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

defaults.setValue(userIdentifier, forKey: "userID")
```

And you can get it:

```
    let userID = defaults.object(forKey: "userID")
```